# Concatenate string and number as number

Tags: vba, excel, string-concatenation

I have a text made of some cells with concatenation. One of the items of the text is a number. How to make it a full number with all the necesarry comas etc.

I have: `on stt 03/06 db corr PLN 60000000 val 03/06 pending`
I need: `on stt 03/06 db corr PLN 60,000,000.00 val 03/06 pending`

I tried with `CDbl(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value)` but the number is still the same.
Please note that the source cell contains the number in correct format : `60,000,000.00` which is downloaded from DB2 database

Many thanks for any help how to achieve that

Answer (score 5):

To concatenate a string and a number you just use `&`, then convert the result to a number with `Val()` function.
Then if you want to format the result number you can use `Format()` function.  Then you get a formatted string.

Example:

```
j = Val("10" & 10)
s = Format(j, "##,###.00")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the use `Format` Function, resolve your problem -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

Maybe `format(60000000,"##,##0.00")`?

Comment: Yes that's it. Format function works perfectly thank you Guys!

Answer (score 0):

If your cell is already formatted appropriately, you can use its `Text` property:

```
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Text
```

Note that because this is the *displayed* value, you can get #### returned if the column width is too narrow for the actual value, but it's still useful where you don't necessarily know the format ahead of time.